# What e-mail address ("From" vs. "Mail From") is considered by my block list?

Tags: exchange-server, email-spam

We are getting a lost of spam /phishing e-mails where the [From] is showing our own domain (e.g. "john@foobar.com"), but the [Mail From] (return-path) in the e-mail header is showing "root@foo-574401.hostbar.com".

Question is now, which e-mail address is actually considered by the Exchange Online block list and could someone point me to the corresponding documentation of Microsoft?

In case the block-list does not consider the [Mail From] we need to setup an transport-rule to address those kind of e-mails?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it:

[See Microsoft documentation Sender filtering procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/antispam-and-antimalware/antispam-protection/sender-filtering-procedures?view=exchserver-2019)

> Sender filtering filters inbound messages by comparing a list of
>   blocked senders to the value of the MAIL FROM command in SMTP
>   connections. For more information about sender filtering and the
>   Sender Filter agent, see Sender filtering.

[See also Sender filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/antispam-and-antimalware/antispam-protection/sender-filtering?view=exchserver-2019)

> Sender filtering compares a list of blocked senders that's maintained
>   by the Exchange administrator to the value of the MAIL FROM command in
>   SMTP connections to determine what to do with inbound email messages
>   from those blocked senders. Sender filtering in Exchange Server is
>   provided by the Sender Filter agent, and is basically unchanged from
>   Exchange Server 2010.